# Python remove line breaks from text

Tags: python, line-breaks

I have text with many line breaks. Every new row should start with the string "/" (that's my choice)
so basically I want to cancel line breaks by identifying new line that does not start with "/" and pop them up to the previous line.
I have this code snippet but it doesn't do the job

```
     mystring = mystring.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your text and what you want???

Comment: Is the text file small enough to read the whole thing into a list, or is it too big to fit into RAM so it needs to be processed a line at a time?

Comment: I took a string with newlines in it and applied your code snippet, and no surprise: it works as I would expect it to. Please give more information, show a sample of your text and how you want the sample to look after removing the line breaks.

Comment: I tried to provide a text example but stackoverflow puts everything in 1 rows. Sorry for the silly Q, but is there a way to upload attachment (text file) ?

Comment: It's not perfect, but you can post text by putting it into a code block. For a small amount of text where you need to show all white space exactly you could just post the output of python's `repr(mystring)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is

```
mystring = mystring.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').replace('/', '\n/')
```

if there is no / anywhere else it your string.  Other wise you will have to iterate of the string line by line

Answer (score 0):

As a hint,if you have your lines in a list like (`l`) you can concatenate the braked lines to main line that `startswith('/')` whit join all of its entries and spit the one string with `/`:

```
>>> l=['/a', 'b', '/c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> ''.join(l)
'/ab/cdef'
>>> ''.join(l).split('/')
['', 'ab', 'cdef']
```